# How to add views circularly in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add views circularly and also dynamically according to the phone resolution without using absolute layout .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Java code instead of XML to implement these views.
With `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()` you can get the screen size.